# Does Intel Graphics Media Accelerator 3600 Series support output to VGA?

Tags: windows-7, graphics-card, vga, external-display

I have an ancient netbook with a VGA socket. I tried to connect an external monitor to it, but it always says there is no signal.

The netbook is running Windows 7. I tried all the usual approaches such as Win-P and pressing the Fn-F2 and Fn-F7 button combinations to switch graphics output to the external monitor. Changing the resolution in the control panel (as shown [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P2xXWNk8kz8)) also didn't help.

Therefore my question: **Does the onboard graphics card [Intel Graphics Media Accelerator 3600 Series](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/products/65926/graphics-drivers/legacy-graphics/intel-graphics-media-accelerator-3600-series.html) support output to VGA?** Can it be that the VGA socket is not connected to the graphics card at all?

I'm using driver version `8.14.8.1096` (according to [this page](https://www.driverscape.com/download/intel%28r%29-graphics-media-accelerator-3600-series) it's the most recent version). Driver manager displays following hardware IDs:

- `PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_0BE2&SUBSYS_21001558&REV_0B`
- `PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_0BE2&SUBSYS_21001558`
- `PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_0BE2&CC_030000`
- `PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_0BE2&CC_0300`

Comment: "Can it be that the VGA socket is not connected to the graphics card at all?" - No; This is not a possibility. Your onboard GPU is connected to the proper components.

Comment: Is the external monitor VGA-only or do you have to press a button to select the input? Have you checked that there are no broken or bent pins in the connectors on the cable?

Comment: @AndrewMorton Re *Is the external monitor VGA-only or do you have to press a button to select the input?*: It supports VGA and HDMI. I always select the VGA mode when testing.

Comment: @AndrewMorton Re *Have you checked that there are no broken or bent pins in the connectors on the cable?*: I don't see any defects with the VGA cable. I bought it today so it's unlikely that it's broken already.

Comment: Does it make sense to try it out with an HDMI cable?

Comment: @DP_ If you've got one to hand, you might as well make sure the monitor accepts some sort of input. Do you happen to have any other source of VGA to test the monitor with?

Comment: @AndrewMorton Tomorrow I can test it with two other notebooks (one with Windows 10 and another with Ubuntu).

Comment: Did you check for video settings in the Bios?

Comment: @Moab I also thought about this, but I could not find anything video-related in the BIOS settings.

Comment: @all Can it be that I am using a wrong VGA cable? Are there different types of VGA cables?

Comment: @DP_ If you've got a basic 15-pin VGA cable, that's all there is to it. Some have lumps near one end or both, some don't - that is just interference suppresion and will make no difference for now.

Comment: FYI: The problem disappeared after I connected the notebook to the monitor using a HDMI cable. Thanks everyone for the help!